# ListView inside Row of Flexible: Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width

Tags: flutter, dart

This is a page of my app. I'm trying to have a space to put widgets and then a sidebar on the right.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Looper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LooperState createState() => _LooperState();
}

class _LooperState extends State<Looper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Row(children: [
          Flexible(
              flex: 21,
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                child: ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: [
                  ],
                ),
              )
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Container(),
            flex: 2,
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

But I get:

```
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width.
```

I tried multiple `BoxFit` like `fitHeight` and `fitWidth` but none of them work. Changing `FittedBox` by a `Container` gives the same error but for `height`;

I kind of understand the error. The ListView doesn't get boundaries from where to grow. However, the Scaffold, as I imagine, already should provide those bounds. I souldn't need to make everything fit inside a `Container` with the width and size of the phone screen.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you can use **shrink wrap**. Try this out.

```
Row(children: [
          Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  Text('Shrink wrap is usefull.')
                ],
              )
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Container(),
            flex: 1,
          ),
        ])
```